# NSNotification Received But Method Is Not Called

Tags: ios, iphone, nsnotificationcenter, nsnotifications, nsnotification

I am posting notification from UIViewController object to UIView object. Notification is called but its method "playSound" is not called.

Below is my code and Thanks in Advance :

```
@interface SettingsViewController : UIViewController <MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate>
{
    MFMailComposeViewController *mailComposer;

}

- (IBAction)btnSoundClicked:(id)sender {
    if(self.btnSound.on)
    {
        NSLog(@"Swith On");
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"soundStatus" object:self.btnSound];
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Switch Off");
    }
}





@interface IAPuzzleBoardView : UIView <AVAudioPlayerDelegate> {

}
- (void)movingThisTile:(CGPoint)tilePoint {

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(playSound:)
                                             name:@"soundStatus"
                                           object:nil];
}
-(void) playSound : (NSNotification *) notification
{
    if ([[notification name] isEqualToString:@"soundStatus"])
    {
        NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"move" ofType:@"wav"];
        theAudio=[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];
        theAudio.delegate = self;
        [theAudio play];
    }
}
```

Comment: i think your IAPuzzleBoardView object is nil at the moment

Comment: No, I have checked IAPuzzleBoardView and its not nil. Its full of its values :( Any more suggestions, Andrey ?

Comment: ok, then probably movingThisTile method is not called or called on a different object, not that you expect

Comment: movingThisTile method is also called and flow is coming on Notification observer, but when i pushing more flow on debugger, its disappers.

Comment: Shall we pass notification from UIViewController to UIView ?

Comment: that's interesting... try to call another method from that notification. what's gonna happen?

Comment: Have change that method to another method but still not calling :(

Comment: well, buddy, i can suggest you nothing except you send me your project and i'll take a look nsobsession@gmail.com

Comment: Sent Project to your email address.....

Comment: See in SettingsVC and IAPuzzleBoardView files....

Comment: look, Hiren, i'm home now and i don't have Mac here to run your project. Just looking over your code didn't give me a clue unfortunately. But tomorrow morning i'll be at work and run the project in Xcode and i'll find what's wrong. It must be something simple

Comment: I would suggest removing the object off the post notification since you have the object as the button there but when you add the observer you are saying the object is nil

Comment: Hey, Hiren, i've checked the app. It works. No problems there. I didn't fix anything. It just works. playSoundFiles method gets called ok after the notification is posted. Run it again and see